# Java Infinite very long loop

Tags: java, loops, long-integer, infinite

I have to do a Java infinite loop but 1 loop would last 24 hours. What is the best way to do it? How could I kill it? Pause and resume it?

Comment: what's the context and what are you trying to do in particular?

Comment: If the loop should end after 24 hours, then it can't be infinite, can it? Or, does one execution of the loop take 24 hours, and executes infinitely afterward? So there would be 7 total loop iterations in a week?

Comment: +1 to dimitrisli for "what are for trying to do". Instead of asking "this is what I need" it is better to ask "this is what I'm trying to accomplish", preferably with some code of how you have approached the problem so far. Your question does not make sense with the same loop being infinite and terminate in 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class with the method:

```
void    schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `while` loop, where you check the elapsed time in the loop condition? This may get pretty expensive if the loop body is short, however.

Answer (score 0):

How about just sleeping for 24 hours?

```
Thread.sleep(24*60*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

"I have to do a Java infinite loop but 1 loop would last 24 hours. " As mentioned if the loops end at some time even if large its not infinite. So, do you mean infinite loop only or the the loop ending 24 hrs? A simple infinite loop is

```
do{
  //do your stuff
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not really explain what you are trying to do, but I will try to give you some tools to work with.

To run a single loop or a predetermined amount of loops asynchronously, you may achieve what you need with [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html).

If you need more control like how many tasks can be running at the same time, you may use a [Thread Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) implementation. This is helpful especially if you don't know how many tasks have to be started and need to restrict memory usage.

I hope this helps.